# About the properties of $x * y = \frac {xy}{x + y + 1}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Let $x * y = \frac {xy}{x + y + 1}.$

$x * y = \frac {xy}{x + y + 1} \neq \frac {x + y + 1}{xy},$ so $*$ is not commutative.

$(x * y) * z = \frac {(xy)z}{x + y + z + 2} = \frac {x(yz)}{z + y + x + 2}$. So, $*$ is associative.

$x * e = \frac {xe}{x + e + 1} = x$, so $e = x + e + 1 = e \text { and } x = -1.$ Further, $\frac {e(-1)}{e + (-1) + 1} = -1.$ So, $*$ has an identity element.

$x * x' = \frac {xx'}{x + x' + 1} = e,$ so $x' = x + x' + 1 = x'.$ Further,  $\frac {x'(-1)}{x' + (-1) + 1} = -1.$ Since $e = x + e + 1 = -1,$ every element has an inverse.

Is the above in\correct?

Comment: That isn't what commutative means. Also, you missed a step in showing associativity.

Comment: The argument about the identity element also doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ graydadd, $y*x = \frac {yx}{y + x +1}$. Does it look better?

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra No not really. I'll post an answer with some pointers if you'd like? I see that you have put in some effort but just need some guidance :)

Comment: @ graydad, sure I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Where is this operation defined?

Comment: @ egreg, the first line in the OP.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra I believe egreg is asking about the domain of the operation. Are $x,y$ real numbers? Integers? Complex numbers?

Comment: @AbstraktAlebra: No, what is the domain of the operation?   What set are $x$ and $y$ members of?

Comment: It's not specified, so I'll just assume it is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra: That doesn't make sense.  What is $(-\frac12)*(-\frac12)$?

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra The question is ill posed, unless you allow partial operations, or extend somehow the definition for the case when $x+y+1=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost as @JonasMeyer pointed out, this operation is not defined on $\Bbb{R}^2$ as you have the set of points $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: x+y=-1 \}$ that make $x \star y$ undefined. This is an important point to address. If you are going on from here, then:

$1.)$ To establish the commutative property, you need to establish that $x\star y = y \star x$. You did correctly write $x\star y = \frac{xy}{x+y+1}$. However, you then flipped the fraction to prove that this operation isn't commutative. Not sure why you did that, but it is not at all the right thing to do. If you evaluate $y \star x$ you get $$y \star x=\frac{yx}{y+x+1} = \frac{xy}{x+y+1} = x \star y$$ hence, the operation *is* commutative.

$2.)$ In showing the associative property, you would need to establish $(x\star y)\star z= x\star (y\star z)$. In the work you have shown in your post above, you are on the right track, but are missing a step. You should evaluate the following: $$(x\star y)\star z =  \frac{(x\star y)z}{(x\star y)+z+1} = \frac{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}z}{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}+z+1}$$ Now you can play around with the algebra and see if you can simplify $\frac{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}z}{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}+z+1}$ to check if it is in fact equal to $x \star (y \star z)$.

$3.)$ For the inverse element $e$, your work above hasn't shown that there is an inverse; you've actually done the opposite. When you set $\frac{xe}{x+e+1} = x$ you inevitably get the equality $$xe = x(x+e+1)$$ We have to be careful here and not divide by $x$ too fast, as @Xoff has pointed out. Otherwise we miss the solution $x=0$. Now that we have caught that case, we assume $x \neq 0$ which makes it safe to divide by $x$. This leads to $x = -1$. So, what you've shown is that *if* there is an $e$ such that $x \star e = x$ then the only elements that will allow $e$ to function as the identity is $x = -1$ or $x=0$. This actually establishes that there is not an identity element, since there is no $x \neq -1,0$ such that $x \star e = x$.

$4.)$ Without an identity, there is no inverse. This is clear because you need the existence of $x^{-1}$ such that $x \star x^{-1} = e$, and we know from above that $e$ does not exist under this operation.

Comment: It is associative.

Comment: @Xoff you are correct. I'll remove my misleading comment from my post.

Comment: Note that $-1$ is not the only absorbing element. There is $0$ also.

Comment: @Xoff also a good catch. I missed that when dividing by $x$ to get $x=-1$

Comment: The operation has not even been defined.  What is the domain?

Comment: @ graydad, is $x * (y * z) = \frac{x\frac{yz}{y+z+1}}{x +\frac{yz}{y +z+1}+1}$?

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra yes that is correct

Comment: @JonasMeyer OP says to assume the domain is $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: @graydad: But that doesn't make sense. It is not defined on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer, I went back and checked my book. I was wrong - the domain was specified by "Each of the following is an operation $*$ on $\mathbb R$" at the beginning of the exercise set. So yeah, the domain is still $\mathbb R.$

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra: That still doesn't make sense.  Again, what is $(-\frac12)*(-\frac12)$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer yes, the infinite set $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: x+y=-1 \}$ is a set of points that are not defined under this operation. One approach to this problem could be to point out that fact. But for people who are new to abstract algebra, it is important to practice going through the motions of showing or disproving commutative, associative, identity and inverse properties of an operation.

Comment: The problem doesn't make sense without pointing out this fact, it is not only a matter of approach. It is also important to know what an operation on a set means, and "going through the motions" of checking whether something is an operation on a set.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I don't think you are wrong, that is a very good point as well. If you were to approach this problem, would you only show it is not defined on $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$ and not bother with the commutative, associative, identity, inverse aspect?

Comment: In fact, the operation (with 'sensible' treatment where the denominator is zero) _does_ have an identity and an inverse over a suitably changed/expanded domain.  One way of making the associativity a little easier (and a guidance towards inverse/identity) is to recognize that $\frac1{x\star y}=\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1{xy}=(\frac1x+1)(\frac1y+1)$.

Comment: @ graydad, this looks messy, but is it correct? $\frac{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}z}{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}+z+1} = \frac{z}{1+z\frac{x+y+1}{xy}+\frac{x+y+1}{xy}} = \frac{z}{\frac {xy+ zx+zy+z + x+y+1}{xy}} = \frac {xyz}{{xy+ z(x+y+1) + x+y+1}} $

$\frac{x\frac{yz}{y+z+1}}{x +\frac{yz}{y +z+1}+1} =\frac{x}{1+x\frac{y+z+1}{yz}+\frac{y+z+1}{yz}} = \frac{z}{\frac {yz+ xy+xz+x + y + z+1}{xy}} = \frac {xyz}{{xy+ z(x+y+1) + x+y+1}} $
So, 
$\frac{x\frac{yz}{y+z+1}}{x +\frac{yz}{y +z+1}+1} = \frac{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}z}{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}+z+1}$

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra haha yeah, the algebra isn't pretty but it looks good to me! Although I would conclude instead with "So, $(x\star y) \star z= x \star (y \star z)$

Comment: @ graydad, about $(3)$, $e$ has to be an identity for all elements in $\mathbb R$, not just two. I see. I don't know why I missed that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra correct; that is exactly the kind of reasoning you want :) Happy to help.